# Is there a way to switch between authentication contexts in the "AzureAD" powershell module the same way you can with the "Az" module?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I'm working on a script that involves jumping between two different user accounts in two different Azure tenants.  With the `Az` powershell module, I can set different auth contexts using:

```
Connect-AzAccount -ContextName "FirstContext" # interactive auth prompt 1
Connect-AzAccount -ContextName "SecondContext" # interactive auth prompt 2
```

then jump between them without any additional interactive prompts like this:

```
Select-AzContext -Name "FirstContext"
# do stuff within the first context
Select-AzContext -Name "SecondContext"
# do stuff within the second context
```

I need to do something similar (jumping back and forth between auth contexts in the same script) using cmdlets in the `AzureAD` powershell module now... Does anyone know this may be able to be achieved?  Both auth contexts require interactive MFA, which `Get-Credential` doesn't seem to support.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to circumvent MFA auth or switch auth contexts? How do you plan to jump between the contexts without using their name? Could you store the result of [Connect-AzAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-2.2.0) such as ```$contextOne = Connect-AzAccount -ContextName "FirstContext"```? is there a reason why you are avoiding fixing up the accounts to follow [least priviledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)?

Comment: @lloyd I want to switch auth contexts on-the-fly _for the `AzureAD` module_.  I already can for the `Az` module, but they're different modules, so I can't take the auth contexts from `Az` and pass them to `AzureAD`.  I'm happy to front-load MFA auth as much as necessary (once per module, per context, so 4x), but I'm looking to avoid re-MFAing within the same PS window when I want to switch between them.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Azure AD PowerShell module does not support to select context.

If you just want to avoid interactive MFA again, you can login with a service principal, after doing something you want, disconnect it and change another service principal.

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "bb58915c-xxxxx5b97ed6c65" -ApplicationId "ec614bcd-d129-4ca4xxxxx19b07" -CertificateThumbprint "F1D9FE13xxxxx8B07D1666"

#do something you want

Disconnect-AzureAD
```

Besides, this is the [Azure AD feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory), you can post it as an idea.

Comment: Not quite what I'm angling for, since the "something I want to do" has to be done as my user context, not as a service principal.

Comment: @Benjin I have answered your question: Azure AD PowerShell module does not support to select context. Using the service principal is my workaround, I think if you grant the permissions for the service principals, they could do most of things instead of your user account.

Comment: I can also confirm that this scenario is not supported. Thanks for the answering Joy!

Comment: @Benjin The MSFT can also confirm that this scenario is not supported, could you click mark to accept it as the answer?